# their younger counterparts

Tags: word-usage

I wrote this sentence:

> Elderly employees usually have a lower level of labor productivity than their younger counterparts

I just want to ask that if I use the word "counterparts" correctly? Do you understand that "counterpart" is a replacement for "employee"? Does it sound natural to a native speaker?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence sounds good and natural, but your explanation misses a subtlety: a **counterpart** (in the definition that would be applicable here) is:

> one having the same function or characteristics as another

The source is [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterpart).

A native speaker familiar with the use of this word would probably assume that "counterparts" in the sentence you provided has a slightly more specific meaning than a repetition of the term "employee" would have - i.e a native speaker might assume that the younger "counterparts" are employees in the same field or having the same job descriptions as the elderly employees they are being compared to.